# PHP : xml_writer , can't use setAttribute to Rootname

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, xmlwriter, setattribute

I'm using xml_writer to create xml files in my CI project. i get the codes from

https://github.com/sandeepeecs/MyDiscountBay.com/blob/master/system/application/controllers/android.php

and

https://github.com/accent-interactive/xml_writer/blob/master/application/controllers/xml.php

i already created xml files with given code successfully. in the code the Rootname is set by

`$xml->setRootName('Submission');`

here i facing a problem in which i want to add some attributes to the Rootname like

```
$xml->setAttribute( my_store,array('xmlns:tns' => 'http://somelink..........'));
```

so the final xml file look like this (sample)

```
<Submission xmlns:tns="http://somelink.....">
   <Header>
        <uid>66166</uid>
   </Header>
</Submission>
```

i already tried

`$xml->setRootName('Submission',array('xmlns:tns' => 'http://somelink..........'));`

but no positive results. ? how can i achive it .? Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The library you use to create the XML does not allow you to specify attributes on the document element.

Therefore you're using the wrong tool for the job.

You probably want to just use [**XMLWriter**](https://php.net/manual/en/ref.xmlwriter.php) directly:

```
// initialize the writer
$writer = new XMLWriter();
$writer->openMemory();
$writer->setIndent(true);
$writer->setIndentString('  ');
$writer->startDocument();

// create the document
$writer->startElement('Submission');
$writer->writeAttribute('xmlns:tns', 'http://somelink..........');

$writer->startElement('Header');

$writer->startElement('uid');
$writer->writeRaw('66166');
$writer->endElement();

// finalize the document and output
$writer->endDocument();
echo $writer->flush();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Submission xmlns:tns="http://somelink..........">
  <Header>
    <uid>66166</uid>
  </Header>
</Submission>
```

As you can see **XMLWriter** on it's own is already pretty straight forward.